# ActionScript 3.0 - coding next button, but it skips to the next next page

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, button

I'm trying to create a simple flash trivial site where each page has a previous, and next button. 
My previous and next buttons seems to work fine when you click them to walk through the movie. (ie. next-> next-> next -> next... ie. prev->prev-> prev->...)

But when I use the 2 buttons together. 
The last next should bring me back to the page where I cliked on the 2nd next, but instead it brings me to the page after.

For example:
page 1 (pressed next)-> page 2 (pressed next)-> page 3(pressed previous)-> page 2 (pressed next) -> give me page 4 (It should give me page 3)

Here is my code for one of the pages:

```
stop();

previous_button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, returnToMarineInvertebrate);
function returnToMarineInvertebrate(event:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop("MarineInvertebrate");
}

hint_button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, goToFishHint);
function goToFishHint(event:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop("FishHint");
}

next_button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, goToFossil);
tail.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, goToFossil);
function goToFossil(event:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop("Fossil");
}
```

I think my logic is correct, but I'm not sure what's wrong. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: I've seen this happen, and it is rather mysterious. Your logic looks squeaky clean from what I can see. Do you have `stop()` on each of your destination frames? (Not saying you SHOULD, just asking.)

Comment: Yep, I do have stop() on every frame. I also have other buttons other than previous and next, ie. the hint button you see, and a return to question button on the hint page, and they all work fine..

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather hit-and-miss bug in Flash that I've faced down a few times. **If you are working with `stop()` on the target frame, `gotoAndStop(targetFrame)` will have mixed success.**

Instead, you're going to want to call `gotoAndPlay();`

The reason for this is, in some cases (not all), `gotoAndStop()` is going to cause Flash to ignore the scripts. That stop call coming from `gotoAndStop()` can sometimes overshoot by a single frame, usually if `stop()` is already there.

Thus, if you switch to `gotoAndPlay(targetFrame)`, and let your `stop()` commands handle braking, you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I tried using gotoAndPlay() and it's still giving the same issue..

Comment: The other alternative is to remove the `stop()` command and use `gotoAndStop()`. This is one of those bugs that has no real solution, from what I've seen.